# Build android application of size greater than 100 Mb

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I need to show one video in my app with size of 400 MB. I am storing my video in raw folder. When i store video of size 50 MB in raw folder and try to run my app, It succesfully runs.

Now when i replace my video with video of size 400 MB, It throws following error while building project.

```
Error:/Volumes/DATA/AndroidStudioProject/DemoApp/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/raw_game_video.mp4.flat failed to read data meta data
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
```

I know that Android playstore apk size limit is 100MB. [APK Size Limit](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)
But it is only for Google play store, right?

I do not want to upload my app on playstore.

So is there any possible way so that i can build my project and create apk with large size video?

**Edit : I wondering that is this issue in my code that it is not running with large size video or Android studio configured in such way that not allow to build project with bigger apk (over 100MB)**

My question is not how to upload android app on store with size more than 100MB, It is how to build app with size more than 100MB.

Comment: Keep your app light. All heavy media files should be on cloud and should be loaded on demand. Nobody likes to download a 100MB app :)

Comment: You are right and i am aware about this scenario but i want to distribute apk with bigger size. Not going to publish this app. It is for personal usage.

Comment: i have a doubt about video file itself, i mean it could be corrupted or invalid format codec ... can you try another large file? or maybe place like 6 or 7 copies of the 50 MB file? **Note:** you know this 400 MB will be stored in internal memory of device, which might be not a good practice ... just saying

Comment: I have tried with another 180MB size video and set property in manifest to prefer external storage for installation. Video format is also okay and it is not corrupted

Comment: For the minus upvoting, please specify reason also. So i can update my question if anything is not properly explained

Comment: Can you list out the full exception `AAPT2 link failed` on what. Also which version of Android Studio you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Note : Just to clear your one part of the question

> I know that Android playstore apk size limit is 100MB. APK Size Limit
>   But it is only for Google play store, right?

Since APK are just another form of archives, say zip archives and this could be more than 100mb. 
See [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36994004).

Provided this, the Package manager use libziparchive which could support files upto 4GB.

See [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libziparchive/).

> So is there any possible way so that i can build my project and create apk with large size video?

For this, there could be various possible ends,You'll need to figure them out. For starter try running on Android M devices( since zip64 is officially supported on 6.0.

Plus looking at your error there's seems to be error in intermediate folder: Trying looking, Is sufficient memory is available on your project location.

PS: There's nothing wrong in the question (removing minus), although the people have already mentioned in above comments about the best practices.

Comment: I have tried by running on Android M and still got error while building project so just curious that is this issue in my code or Android studio configured in such way that not allow to build project with bigger apk (over 100MB)

Comment: @Beena , I'm afraid I can't comment on your code, since I haven't look at it,but have you enabled multiDex support for your app? You can use 'dexOptions {
        additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex', '--set-max-idx-number=40000']
    }'  . See this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html